# Is there a way to see statistics on this site's usage?

Tags: discussion

After a recent [question about Reddit](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3838/29944), I was wondering whether we have current data to site statistics such as the one linked to in this answer from Joseph Weissman to an old question about promoting this SE: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/118/29944

Here is the link to Area 51. I assume this is old data, but perhaps it is current: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy

---

The following are sources from the comments for site statistics:

- [Here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions) is a sortable list comparing an overview of all stack exchange statistics. Thanks to @Eliran.
- For those with 5000+ reputation [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) is access to more detailed statistics about this stack exchange.  Thanks to @PhilipKlocking

Comment: you can see some stats here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: [Earn 
5,000 reputation?!](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)